# How the executor memory is determined while running pyspark in local mode?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

If I submit spark program as

->submit-spark --driver-memory 500M   --executor-memory 300M spark_dataframe_example.py

then executor memory allocated is "110 MiB"  even though I have set it as "300 M" .See image below:-

[image]
If I submit spark program as

-> spark-submit --driver-memory 1G   --executor-memory 200M  --num-executors 2 spark_dataframe_example.py

then executor memory  allocated is "413.9 MiB" even though I have set it as "200 M".See image below:-

[image]

So could someone confirm how this executor memory is allocated?

Comment: In local mode you cannot set the executor memory, you don´t really have executors as you see in the Spark UI too, you have only a driver.

Answer (score 2):

As was said in the comments, the `--executor-memory` flag is ignored in local mode. To confirm this, try running your `spark-submit` command with a ridiculously high `--executor-memory` flag (bigger than your machine): it won't complain because it is ignored.

Running Spark in local mode is a bit of an exception, since your driver and executor run inside of a single JVM. So the value that counts here is your `--driver-memory` flag.

Now, where do those 110MB and 413.9MB come from? In version 3.3.2 - the most recent version at the time of this post - they are the result of [this calculation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5103e00c4ce5fcc4264ca9c4df12295d42557af6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/memory/UnifiedMemoryManager.scala#L210-L235):

```scala
    val systemMemory = conf.get(TEST_MEMORY)
    val reservedMemory = conf.getLong(TEST_RESERVED_MEMORY.key,
      if (conf.contains(IS_TESTING)) 0 else RESERVED_SYSTEM_MEMORY_BYTES)

    // skipping some irrelevant lines
    ...

    val usableMemory = systemMemory - reservedMemory
    val memoryFraction = conf.get(config.MEMORY_FRACTION)
    (usableMemory * memoryFraction).toLong
```

There are 3 values which we need to find out where they come from:

- `systemMemory` comes from `TEST_MEMORY` which finally is the `Xmx` value of your running JVM process. This will always be a bit smaller than your `--driver-memory` but close to it. You don't set this yourself, Spark does that for you in function of your memory requirements.
- `reservedMemory` will be defined by `RESERVED_SYSTEM_MEMORY_BYTES` (since we're not in a testing scenario) and this value is 314572800 (300MB).
- `memoryFraction` is 0.6 in the default scenario, which seems to be the case for you.

The final calculation is thus: `(systemMemory - reservedMemory)*memoryFraction

Now we can do our calculations!

#### Your first case

`--driver-memory` was 500M, so let's calculate:

- (524288000 - 314572800) * 0.6 = 125829120 = 120MB
- since we know the `Xmx` value of your JVM process is close to, but smaller than `--driver-memory` this is very close to 110MB!

#### Your second case

`--driver-memory` was 1G, so let's calculate:

- (1048576000 - 314572800) * 0.6 = 440401920 = 420MB
- since we know the `Xmx` value of your JVM process is close to, but smaller than `--driver-memory` this is very close to 413.9MB!